# quarkus docker container doesn't work on arm platform: exec ./application: exec format error

Tags: docker, arm, github-actions, exec, quarkus

I am trying to build my quarkus backend for arm and amd architectures. It does currently build with the following script which should build for arm too, but i get: `exec ./application: exec format error`, if i try to run it using `docker run` on an arm based platform.

Location/Host: https://cloud.oracle.com
Image: Canonical-Ubuntu-22.04-aarch64-2023.10.13-0
Shape: VM.Standard.A1.Flex

github-workflow

```yaml
  test-and-build-backend:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Java environment
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: "17"
          distribution: "temurin"

      - name: Build Backend
        run: |
          cd backend
          chmod +x mvnw
          ./mvnw package -Dnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true

      - name: Archive Backend
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: backend
          path: backend/target


push-backend-to-docker-hub:
    needs: test-and-build-backend
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: backend
          path: ./backend/target

      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v3

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3

      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Build and push backend
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          push: true
          tags: cre8ivemind/creative-mind-backend:latest
          platforms: linux/amd64,linux/arm64
          context: ./backend
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.8
WORKDIR /work/
RUN chown 1001 /work \
    && chmod "g+rwX" /work \
    && chown 1001:root /work
COPY --chown=1001:root target/*-runner /work/application

RUN chmod +x /work/application

EXPOSE 8080
USER 1001

ENTRYPOINT ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Comment: I used OCI too with [this](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/test-microservice-frameworks/blob/main/.github/workflows/oci-arm64.bak), I know in theory setup-java will understand the architecture and use arm but in my yml I set `architecture: aarch64` probably also had issues. I do not remember the details but that yaml was working fine, at some point I realize free tier was not as fast as github runners so I stopped using it.